# How can I insert a record in the table of mysql from textboxes of html?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, web

1. I have a jsp file for html and myservlet.java file for Java. I am confused about in which file I will write an insert query either in jsp or Java?.
2. What is an insert query for netbean?Is it correct?

   String query = "INSERT INTO teacher1 (id,name) " + "VALUES (" + 1 + ", '" + aaa + "')";

**myservlet.java**

```
class dbconn {

    Connection c1 = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    private final String ac;
    private final String aaa;

    dbconn() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            c1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher", "root", "abcde");

        } catch (Exception cnfe) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
            System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
            System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");
        }
        try {
            st = (Statement) c1.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Statement Created Successfully");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");

        }
        if (c1 != null) {
            System.out.println("Hooray! We connected to the database!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("We should never get here.");
        }
        String query = "INSERT INTO teacher1 (id,name) "
                + "VALUES (" + 1 + ", '" + aaa + "')";       // insert query is this
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet myservlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body >");

            out.println("<h1>Servlet myservlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            String name = request.getParameter("firstname");
            out.println("<h2>" + name + "</h2>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    public String getServletInfo() {

        return "Short description";

    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <form action="myservlet"  method="GET"    >

            First name:<br> 
            <input type="text" name="firstname"/> 
            <br> 
            Last name:
            <br> 
            <input type="text" name="lastname" /> 
            <br>  <br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` with substitutions (`?`) instead of building the SQL piecemeal as you are suggesting.  Your version is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: where i should write the insert query either in jsp or java file. please correct the insert query syntax thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.